# What am I missing in this Django model relationship

Tags: django

I have a `CustomUser` model, and a `Blog` model.

CustomUser model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="", blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True)
    country = models.CharField( max_length=50, default="", blank=True, choices=settings.COUNTRIES_LIST)
    about_me = models.TextField(max_length=225, default="", blank=True)
    photo_url = models.TextField(null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # can login
```

Blog model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, null=True,  verbose_name=_('user'), related_name="%(class)s_blogs",  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    blog_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, default=get_id, unique=True, editable=False)
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    blog_description = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    blog = FroalaField()
    dynamic_link = models.CharField(max_length=225, null=False, default="")
    blog_type = models.CharField( max_length=50, null=False, choices=BLOGSTYPE_LIST)
    blog_status   = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, default="unapproved")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My understanding is that I could use the related_name to get all blogs by a user.

```
>>> from users.models import CustomerUser
>>> user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> user.blog_blogs.all()
<BlogQuerySet []>
```

As you must have seen, this turns to always return but an empty queryset, even though there are blog entries by that user.

So is it am not understanding here?
Thank you.

Comment: `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL===CustomUser` ?

Comment: @IvanStarostin yes that's done

Comment: Can you please add all fields in model in quesion?

Comment: @LearnToday Can you Please All Fields!

Comment: @MKPatel  I added the fields, I also removed the pass as recommended

Comment: I think you have to use `set` as `user.blog_set.all()`.

Comment: @MKPatel AttributeError: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'blog_set'

Comment: @LearnToday Can you able to get the user from blog object?

Comment: Please show the result of `Blog.objects.filter(user_id=1,)`

Comment: @IvanStarostin this ```Blog.objects.filter(user_id=1,)``` works. I don't understand why the related_name won't

Comment: ```>>> Blog.objects.filter(user_id=2,)
<BlogQuerySet [<Blog: 6d260ae8>, <Blog: eab07215>]>```

Comment: I think as per `related_name` you should run either `user.blogs_blogs.all()` OR `user.Blogs_blogs.all()`

Comment: @MKPatel I get the same error

Comment: You are getting `AttributeError: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'blogs_blogs' ` ?

Comment: yes that ```AttributeError: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'blogs_blogs'
>>> user.Blogs_blogs.all()```

Comment: Have you checked that which user you are getting with `CustomUser.objects.get(pk=1)` is assigned to any blogs or not in your db.

Comment: `Blog.objects.filter(user_id=2,)` is this a joke? Why 2 when your question is about 1?

Comment: @IvanStarostin 2 is a user. Why would that be too confusing? Must there be one user in the database? What is different from using user 1 or user 2? both users have blogs in the database.